# How to move an element symmetrically in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, edges, faces

I want to ask how to move an element symmetrically in edit mode.
Like this pic, I want this object be wider in both sides, all I know is to do grabbing for both sides relatively, but this is not smart and not true symmetric.
[image]

I tried scale in y axis but this also scaled my curve parts like this pic:
[image]

So is there any better way to do this? Thanks a lot!

blend file:[image]

Comment: Make sure your transform pivot is set to "median point" (default), then select both "sides" and scale (S) on the Y axis.

Comment: You can delete half portion and use a mirror modifier. Now,moving one part moves the second symmetrically

Comment: @Christopher Bennett Thank you for reply. I'm new to blender, can I ask where can I find this "transform pivot"?

Comment: @Raj jaiswal Hi. I was considering this way but I want to know is there a way that don use cutting cause I have to apply these modifiers every times that annoying me. Thank you for reply anyway.

Comment: The transform pivot is at the  top-center of your viewport (to the left of the magnet) - it's a drop down menu.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett Thank you. I checked the transform pivot is in "median point" as pic above showed. This doesn't make any change as you can see in my second pic. My curve was stretched from 45 degrees to less then 45 degrees.

Comment: Yeah, ok. In that case, go with the answer below (remove half your mesh then - mirror modifier). It's s the only practical way to move both "sides" away from each-other at once like that. Otherwise, you can stick to manually moving them. Remember you can move by axis and by increment (ex: `G` (move) `+ Y` (Y-axis) `+ 5` (5 units)). You can at least move the separate sides by the same distance if you want to keep symmetry.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett move by increment is a good idea! This maybe not the smartest way but easist way I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest and most surefire way is create a mirror modifier.

Split your object down the middle in Edit Mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to generate a new edge loop going all the way around the object at its center. After activating this shortcut, float your cursor a bit along a horizontal edge near the top or bottom center of your object until you see a vertical division appear which snaps to the centerline of the object. Then left-click immediately afterwards one single time to commit to that division, then right-click one single time to cancel any further mode actions, which will then commit to this edit.

Now remove half of your model. Box select the half to be removed. Do this in an orthographic, wireframe front view, to make sure you don't miss any of the desired parts. Also do it with *Face Selection* mode active (so that you are sure to select *faces* and *not* edges or vertices). Then delete these faces so that only half of your model remains.

Finally, create a **mirror modifier** from the modifier tab (wrench icon) in the Properties Panel. Assuming your object's pivot center is properly aligned with the cut you made (which it typically will be by default), the mirrored half will be positioned correctly in relation to the original half, without the need for further settings changes. The mirrored half will perfectly mimic the other half whenever you tweak it in Edit mode.

When you are done modeling, you should probably *apply* the mirror modifier, which will make the mirrored results permanent, and give you two proper sides to the object afterwards. Note that you cannot do this *apply* function while still in Edit mode.

Comment: Thank you for your kind instruction. There's one thing I stumbled: I can not create a full loop cut going all the way of my object, only some part. Maybe because I used bevel and some modifiers to it. So I guess I have to use another boolean modifier in object mode to cut it in half?

Comment: If you can't get the loop cut to go all the way around, there is some feature of the topology that is likely interfereing with it. There is an other way to achieve this result without using loop cuts, but it's a bit harder to describe: Knife Project is a feature that can slice your object however you want, without any issues arising from interfering topology.

Comment: I updated blend file to my post. Can you take a look to it? Yeah I considered knife tool but I just can not use it well. The point is I don't know my cut is centered or not even I turned on magnet function cause magnet won't functional after first click. Maybe I use it wrong?

Comment: I looked at it. There may be some problems with it. For one, there are at least 177 double vertices, which can be cleaned up in Edit mode under Mesh > Cleanup > Merge by Distance. Also, your model is made up of two or more primitives which have been joined together, instead of being one continuous mesh. If it was continuous, it would make your future editing efforts cleaner and easier. The reason your loop cuts wouldn't work is because of the rounded bevels. They evidently confuse the loop cut algorithm. Now, I know you can't get rid of them, and there's a solution (see below).

Comment: View the front of your model with keypad 3, and then go into Edit mode. Then at the top of the screen, go to the Mesh menu and look for the Bisect tool. It lets you draw a dotted line where you want a cut. Try to get it close to the center of your model. You can tweak its position after placing it. I found that even with all your model's issues, the bisect tool worked quickly and easily to cut it in half anyway. I was able to get a mirror modifier on it afterwards. It seemed to work, but I'm still concerned about your model being more than one joined primitives. May cause problems later.

Comment: Thank you! I made a perfect cut follow your instruction and now I can add mirror modifier to it. Yeah I know combine multiple objects is not a good idea. Need more to learn about modeling.

Comment: Glad to know you got it working. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Mirror Modifier**

Divide your object in half (Remove half of your model), and then apply mirror modifier (from modifier properties tab i.e. wrench symbol) on it (choose correct axis)

Turn on clipping (it makes easy to join both sides)

Apply modifier to make your mirror modifier after you are done modelling